# KDevelop function deprecation warnings

Tags: c, configuration, kdevelop

I'm using `g_str_to_ascii()` function from glib library in KDevelop project. The function was added in glib 2.40 and I'm using even newer version of that library, but it's being marked by app as deprecated. Is there any way to guide KDevelop, to not mark that function as deprecated?

[KDevelop screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dwRmK.png)

Comment: Do you see the same warning when building your code?

Comment: No, only in KDevelop "Problems - Parser" tool.

Comment: You can add `-Wdeprecated-declarations` somewhere in parser settings.

Comment: I can add in "Configure Project -> Language Support -> C/C++ Parser" `-Wno-deprecated-declarations` and then I get rid off all deprecations warnigs, but it's not like true solution.

Comment: If you are using GCC, make sure that parser settings is set to GCC mode, not Clang.